# embedding a video from onedrive in a wordpress blog post

Tags: wordpress, html, onedrive

Ive got a very basic WordPress website using the new 2017 theme and I'm trying to embed a simple video.  The video is on OneDrive, but it should be the same as YouTube or any other source, and I can play the video fine in a plain HTML page.

When I insert the following HTML iframe in my post:

```
<iframe src="https://onedrive.live.com/embed?cid=3F3E866DF352275A&resid=3F3E866DF352275A%21106&authkey=ADg-86mHmhzI3mw" width="320" height="180" frameborder="0" scrolling="no" allowfullscreen></iframe>
```

It shows a small blank frame for a few seconds when I preview the post, then it jumps to the onedrive embedded link showing the video full screen, so you cant see the post.

I tried using a plugin too and that didn't work either, somehow it had the same problem.  I was using FV player which seems to be very popular but when I try to embed this video it says there "Video Issues".  I know there's nothing wrong with the video because, again, I can insert this iframe in a  plain HTML page and it works no problem.  Only when I embed the iframe in a wordpress post does it pop out into the onedrive link and go full screen.

Any suggestions?  This should just work and I don't know what I'm missing.

Answer (score 1):

src="https://onedrive.live.com/**embed**?cid=3F3E866DF352275A&resid=3F3E866DF352275A%21106&authkey=ADg-86mHmhzI3mw"

replace the embed with download. and use normal video tag instead of iframe.

src="https://onedrive.live.com/**download**?cid=3F3E866DF352275A&resid=3F3E866DF352275A%21106&authkey=ADg-86mHmhzI3mw"